# SnowScripting: SQL compilation error: syntax error line 6 at position 13 unexpected '<EOF>'

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I'm new with Snowflake and creating a procedure in Snowflake using Snow Scripting. What could possibly be wrong?

```
create or replace procedure test_procedure(p_dob date)
returns varchar
language sql
as
declare
    v_age NUMBER;
begin
    v_age := datediff(year, p_dob, current_date);
    return 'Your age is '||v_age::varchar;
end;
```

Error msg: SQL compilation error: syntax error line 6 at position 17 unexpected ''.

Answer (score 0):

The code is all right using Snowsgihgt UI, though it should be `CURRENT_DATE()` instead of `CURRENT_DATE`. To make it run using ClassicUI is should be delimited with `$$`:

```
create or replace procedure test_procedure(p_dob date)
returns varchar
language sql
as
$$
declare
    v_age NUMBER;
begin
    v_age := datediff(year, p_dob, current_date());
    return 'Your age is '||v_age::varchar;
end;
$$;
    
call test_procedure('2022-01-01');
```

More at: [Using String Constant Delimiters Around a Block in a Stored Procedure](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/running-examples.html#using-string-constant-delimiters-around-a-block-in-a-stored-procedure)